# Domain relationship module for drupal 7?

Tags: 7, domain-access

I want to create parent/child relationship in domain access module.
My use case is:

Parent Domain:
->child Domain

When I add a node to the child Domain it should also be automatically created on the parent Domain with an administrator approval required on the parent domain.

Means when I created a node on child domain it should be published and visible to the users on the child domain but it should not be visible to the user on the parent domain unless the administrator approve it.

I looked at the domain relationship module but it is only for drupal 6. Is there any alternative for domain relationship module for drupal 7?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need another module.
Just use [Domain Access](https://www.drupal.org/project/domain).

You can let users choose to which domain this node will be published.
Make sure that the user that needs to approve the node has the following permissions:

- **Publish content to any assigned domain**
- **Set domain access status for all content**.